# Último documento insertado en MongoDB

Tags: php, json, mongodb

Estoy tratando de sacar el último documento insertado en MongoDB con PHP. Mi intención en costruir una estructura apta para Highcharts y poder mostrar los datos en forma de estadísticas.
Hasta ahora tengo este código

```
$client = new MongoDB\client;
$database = $client->test;
$collection = $database->pruebas;

$documentlist = $collection->find();

echo "[";
foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
    echo "[";
    echo $doc->fecha;
    echo ",";
    echo $doc->magnitud5->valor;
    echo "]";
    echo ",";
}
echo "]";
```

Necesito decirle en este foreach que si es el último elemento no me ponga una coma `echo ",";`.
He probado con

```
if ($element === end($array))
    echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
```

También con esta estructura

```
echo "[";
foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
    if ($i >= 0) {
        echo "[";
        echo $doc->fecha;
        echo ",";
        echo $doc->magnitud5->valor;
        echo "]";
        echo ",";
    } else if ($i == $len -1) {
        echo "";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "]";
```

Y con muchas mas, pero estas (a mi parecer) son las que mas se acercan al resultado que busco.  Pero nada... no fuciona y siemore sale una `,` al final.

¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna manera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está resuelto, por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro dejo por aquí el código.

```
$numItems = $collection->count();
$i = 0;

echo "[";
foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
    echo "[";
    echo $doc->fecha;
    echo ",";
    echo $doc->magnitud5->valor;
    echo "]";
    if(!(++$i === $numItems)) {
        echo ",";
    }
}
echo "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el `$index` del `foreach` para mostrar siempre que sea menor al `$total`.

```
$client = new MongoDB\client;
$database = $client->test;
$collection = $database->pruebas;

$documentlist = $collection->find();
$total = collection->count() - 1;

echo "[";
foreach ($documentlist as $index => $doc) {
    echo "[";
    echo $doc->fecha;
    echo ",";
    echo $doc->magnitud5->valor;
    echo "]";
    if ($total > $index) {
       echo ",";
    }
}
echo "]";
```

Comment: Eso también lo pensé, pero me lanza un Warning. `Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: Probá reemplazando `count($documentlist)` por `$collection->count()`.

Comment: Si, eso si. Justo como lo puse yo en mi respuesta. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!